# java abstract class constructor wont work as predicted

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, super

So I have this abstract class:

```
abstract class Shape
{
   int Width;
   int Height;
   final String nazwaKształtu;

   public Shape(int w, String kształt)
   {
       nazwaKształtu = kształt;
   }
   public Shape(int w, int h, String kształt)
   {
       nazwaKształtu = kształt;
   }

   void setWidth(int w)
   {
       Width = w;
   }

}
```

And another class shape:

```
class Square extends Shape
{
    Square(int w, String kształt) {
        super(kształt);               // I get an error here
        Width = w;
        Height = w;
    }

    @Override
    void setWidth(int w)
    {
        Width = w;
        Height = w;
    }
    public int getWidth()
    {
        return Width;
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return Height;
    }
}
```

But I get an error message telling me that something is wrong with the types. But in my abstract class I do have a constructor that should be applicable. When I change constructor in my Square class to:

```
Square(int w) {
        super("Prostokąt");
        Width = w;
        Height = w;
    }
```

it still wont work. What mistake did I make?

Comment: What are you passing as an argument to the super constructor? What type(s) does the super constructor expect?

Comment: Doesn't your shape constructor take 2 arguments. Why are you passing only one in your super call on the Square class?

Comment: `String kształt;` ... `super(kształt);`. I don't see a `Shape` constructor that takes only a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

This line `super(kształt);`  means, that you call constructor of your parent, which takes exactly one one parameter and because `kształt` is String, you have to have constructor, which takes one String as parameter to use that super method.

Or more like it - with your example, you want to use this `super(w, kształt);` which calls this constructor :  `public Shape(int w, String kształt)`

Comment: @lvi Because in that case `Product` has a constructor `Product(int)`, which matches `super(2)` from a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Line `super(kształt)` is trying to find the constructor which accept only `String` argument but it could not find any constructor with that signature.

You are not providing the constructor which accept only `String` in your shape class. All the provided constructor are accepting different argument. Java Compiler is not able to find the constructor with only String as argument.

Choice 1 - You can add the constructor in super class.

```
public Shape(String kształt)
   {
       nazwaKształtu = kształt;
   }
```

Choice 2 - if for some reason you are not able to add constructor in super class then you may need to call the corresponding constructor like

`super(w, ksztatt);`

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you could explain why you believe that adding that constructor is the right thing to do. It may not be appropriate to add another constructor to `Shape`.

Comment: @JasonC I think I am continuously trying to improve my answer.

Comment: Yes, but you are missing one of the key points: It *appears* that a more appropriate course of action would be for the OP to use `super(w, kształt)` instead, based on an educated guess about his intentions, and looking at his code. While adding a `Shape(String)` constructor absolutely solves the immediate compilation problem, can you explain why you believe it is the *right thing to do* in this context? If the OP starts blindly adding super-constructors to match, without knowing why, that could easily cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: Thanks,I get your point completely and I have updated my answer as well.